# My post does not show up

Tags: posts, errors

I'm facing a WordPress strange behavior. One of [my posts](http://www.feras-odeh.com/java/h2_embeded_database_java/) is not showing up. If I open post editor I can find the post full text and in my home page I can see an excerpt of this post. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You other posts are very much visible.This seems to be a strange behavior indeed.Your blog seems to be good enough performance wise. I would suggest you try to delete the post and prepare a new one . May be this must solve the problem .

Comment: That's what I thought about, but If I did that I'll lose post related data.

Comment: Related data as such what? You can always keep a copy of your post and comments as such right? :)